# Optimize running time of MySQL query

Tags: mysql, yii

There is a table users with primary key as user_id and an indexed column called verified.
Another table user_profile has PK as profile_id and FK as user_id and has a column  - name

Now, I need to find all verified users and their names. so i need to join these 2 tables on user_id -

Query becomes -

```
select p.name from user_profile p inner join user u on p.user_id = u.user_id
where u.verified = 1;
```

There are 700000 records in profile table and same number of records in user table. This query above takes 13 seconds to run. Please let me know, how can I optimize the running time.

MySQL version 5.5 , YII

### EDIT

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_profile` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `regyear` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `occupation` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `street` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `zip` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `state` (`state`),
  KEY `firstname` (`firstname`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=626494 ;
```

---

--

### -- Table structure for table `tbl_user`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_user` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `createtime` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `lastvisit` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `verified` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),
  KEY `status` (`status`),
  KEY `verified` (`verified`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=626494 ;
```

Output of EXPLAIN SELECT - I have written same query as above but substituting 999 for 1 and using column status instead of verified, which is equivalent to problem statement.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT p.firstname
FROM tbl_profile p
INNER JOIN tbl_user u ON p.user_id = u.id
WHERE u.status =999
+----+-------------+-------+------+----------------+---------+---------+-------------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys  | key     | key_len | ref         | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+----------------+---------+---------+-------------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | u     | ref  | PRIMARY,status | status  | 4       | const       | 313333 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | p     | ref  | user_id        | user_id | 4       | newone.u.id |      1 |             |
+----+-------------+-------+------+----------------+---------+---------+-------------+--------+-------------+
```

Comment: What indexes do you have on the tables? Add the `CREATE TABLE` statements of the 2 tables and the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: Can a user have many profiles?

Comment: no , there is just 1 profile for a user and I think you would be suggesting to join them and make 1 table ? Actually user table is only used for login and the other table has profile related data.

Comment: No, I've added my suggestion as an answer. No idea if Yii will have any problems with that change. Some ORMs/frameworks have issues with tables without auto-incrementing PKs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Suggestion 1**

Adding an index on `(user_id, first_name)` will improve efficiency of this specific query:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_profile
  ADD INDEX user_id_first_name_IX             -- just a name for the index
    (user_id, first_name) ;
```

But if you also have similar queries, where you are selecting other columns, you'll need more indexes like this. And adding 5-10 indexes in the table is not too bad (it will only slow your inserts a bit.) But adding too many indexes will be harmful in the end.

---

**Suggestion 2**

If every user has maximum of 1 profile, then there is no need to have an auto-incrementing `id` in table `profiles`. I suggest you drop that column and make the `user_id` the primary key. I would also make that a foreign key as well:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_profile
  DROP PRIMARY KEY,
  DROP COLUMN id,
  ADD CONSTRAINT profile_PK
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id),
  ADD CONSTRAINT user_profile_FK 
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
    REFERENCES tbl_user (id) ;
```

This is far better than suggestion 1, as you will basically make the `user_id` the clustered index of the table. Any query that uses `user_id` for a join on this table will be able to use this (primary and clustered) index.

Answer (score -1):

You may gain a performance improvement by moving the condition into the join's `ON` clause:

```
select p.name
from user_profile p
join user u on p.user_id = u.user_id and u.verified = 1;
```

This reason it may perform better is that the `WHERE` clause is evaluated *after* all rows are joined - it's a *filter* on the result set. However the `ON` condition is evaluated *as the join is being made*, so there is a possibility that the database will have to deal with a lot less rows, and thus a lot less memory/resources.

Other than that change, I can't see anything else you could do.

Comment: I don't know why the downvote , I have to try each suggestion and see which runs fastest.

Comment: That's very sensible to try them. Often it's the fastest and best way tontine your queries - make some changes and compare timings. If you're testing them all, it would be helpful to everyone to add a comment to all answers saying how it performed